# How Python threading Timer work internally?

Tags: python, multithreading, timer, scheduler

I want to know how python `threading.Timer` works.

In more detail, When i run a couple of `threading.Timer`, does it run separate thread for counting a time and running the handler ?

Or one thread manages and counts a couple of timer together ?

I am asking because my application need to schedule many event, But

If threading.Timer runs separate each thread for counting a timer, and i run many timers, it may affect performance so much.

So i am worry that if i have to implement a scheduler running only one thread if it has big effect in performance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`threading.Timer` class is a subclass of `threading.Thread` and basically it just runs a separate thread in which it sleeps for the specified amount of time and runs the corresponding function.

It is definitely **not** an efficient way to schedule events. Better way is to do the scheduling in a single thread by using `Queue.PriorityQueue` in which you would put your events where "priority" actually means "next fire date". Similar to how cron works.

Or even better: use something that already exists, do not reinvent the wheel: Cron, Celery, whatever...

A very simplified example of making a scheduler via `Queue.PriorityQueue`:

```
import time
from Queue import PriorityQueue

class Task(object):
    def __init__(self, fn, crontab):
        # TODO: it should be possible to pass args, kwargs
        # so that fn can be called with fn(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fn = fn
        self.crontab = crontab

    def get_next_fire_date(self):
        # TODO: evaluate next fire date based on self.crontab
        pass

class Scheduler(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.event_queue = PriorityQueue()
        self.new_task = False

    def schedule_task(self, fn, crontab):
        # TODO: add scheduling language, crontab or something
        task = Task(fn, crontab)
        next_fire = task.get_next_fire_date()
        if next_fire:
            self.new_task = True
            self.event_queue.put((next_fire, task))

    def run(self):
        self.new_task = False

        # TODO: do we really want an infinite loop?
        while True:
            # TODO: actually we want .get() with timeout and to handle
            # the case when the queue is empty
            next_fire, task = self.event_queue.get()

            # incremental sleep so that we can check
            # if new tasks arrived in the meantime
            sleep_for = int(next_fire - time.time())
            for _ in xrange(sleep_for):
                time.sleep(1)
                if self.new_task:
                    self.new_task = False
                    self.event_queue.put((next_fire, task))
                    continue

            # TODO: run in separate thread?
            task.fn()

            time.sleep(1)
            next_fire = task.get_next_fire_date()

            if next_fire:
                event_queue.put((next_fire, task))

def test():
    return 'hello world'

sch = Scheduler()
sch.schedule_task(test, '5 * * * *')
sch.schedule_task(test, '0 22 * * 1-5')
sch.schedule_task(test, '1 1 * * *')
sch.run()
```

It's just an idea. You would have to properly implement both `Task` and `Scheduler` classes, i.e. `get_next_fire_date` method plus some kind of scheduling language (crontab?) and error handling. I still strongly suggest to use one of the existing libraries.

Comment: Could you show a simple example how to implement a scheduler using `Queue.PriorityQueue` ? it doesn't make sense for me.

Comment: @asleea Added an example.

Answer (score 1):

From the CPython 2.7 source:

```
def Timer(*args, **kwargs):
    """Factory function to create a Timer object.

    Timers call a function after a specified number of seconds:

        t = Timer(30.0, f, args=[], kwargs={})
        t.start()
        t.cancel()     # stop the timer's action if it's still waiting

    """
    return _Timer(*args, **kwargs)

class _Timer(Thread):
    """Call a function after a specified number of seconds:

            t = Timer(30.0, f, args=[], kwargs={})
            t.start()
            t.cancel()     # stop the timer's action if it's still waiting

    """

    def __init__(self, interval, function, args=[], kwargs={}):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.interval = interval
        self.function = function
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.finished = Event()

    def cancel(self):
        """Stop the timer if it hasn't finished yet"""
        self.finished.set()

    def run(self):
        self.finished.wait(self.interval)
        if not self.finished.is_set():
            self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        self.finished.set()
```

As said in another answer, it is a separate thread (since it subclasses Thread). The callback function when the timer runs out is called from the new thread.